# Where did these hex named folders come from?

Tags: windows, hex, directory

First off, I am using Windows XP.  I have multiple hard drives and it looks like something decided to make some folders on the second one ( which is just a data drive, no os ).  These folders all have names like "e69f29f1b1f166d3d30b8c9f7156ba" and "bd92c24cc278614082cd88e7a64b".  They contain folders named update, whose "access is denied",  so my best guess would be they are Windows updates.  So I probably can't get rid of them but could someone at least explain what they are and why they are on the wrong drive?

Comment: You can delete them, at least I always do, just take ownership of the folder and its contents then delete away (if they are truly unused) happy trails buddy!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windows will always use the hard drive with the most space to download windows updates.  This is what happened to you.

http://computershopper.com/forums/showthread.php?t=265